# rails pagination and where clause with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Hello i have this models

**models/store/store.rb**

```
class Store::Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :store_products
  has_many :products, :through => :store_products
end
```

**models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name ...
  has_many :store_products
  has_many :stores, :through => :store_products
end
```

**models/store/store_product.rb**

```
class Store::StoreProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "stores_products"
    attr_accessible :store_id, :product_id
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :product
end
```

and im getting params['store_ids'] via post to controller action

```
>> params['store_ids']
=> ["1", "2"]
```

where i have this code

```
>> @products = Product.joins(:stores).where("stores.id IN (?)", params[:store_ids])
```

it throw error
`#<NameError: uninitialized constant Product::StoreProduct>`

How can i fix this (select products only in some stores) ? :-) Thank you

edit : MORE INFO :

Folder Structure

```
app/controllers/store/main_controller.rb
app/controllers/store/stores_controller.rb

app/models/store/store.rb
app/models/store/store_product.rb
app/models/product.rb
```

the code is in

```
class Store::MainController < ApplicationController
def index
  if params['store_ids'] then 
       @products = Product.joins(:stores)...
  else
      @products = Product.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'name asc', per_page: 10
  end
end
```

Part of DB Schema:
**stores_products**

```
id
product_id
store_id
```

**products**

```
id
name
...
```

**stores**

```
id
name
...
```

**SOLUTION (thanks to Gotva)**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, ...

  has_many :store_products, class_name: "Store::StoreProduct"
  has_many :stores, :through => :store_products
end

class Store::Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :store_products, class_name: "Store::StoreProduct"
  has_many :products, :through => :store_products
end

class Store::StoreProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "stores_products"
    attr_accessible :store_id, :product_id

    belongs_to :store, class_name: "Store::Store"
    belongs_to :product, class_name: "Product"
end
```

and finally

```
@products = Product.joins(:stores).where("stores.id IN (?)", params[:store_ids]).paginate(page: params[:page], order: 'products.name asc', per_page: 10)
```

Comment: Are you using Kaminari?

Comment: hi, im using will_pagination

Comment: but i can switch to kaminari if it helps

Comment: Muflix, as long as your paginate method and selected stores method return ActiveRecord::Reltion object, aka scoped, you can always chain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@products = Product.joins(:stores).where("#{Store::Store.table_name}.id IN (?)", params[:store_ids]).paginate(page: params[:page], order: 'name asc', per_page: 10)
```

maybe it will duplicate products so add method `uniq` after `where`, this applies `distinct` in the query

Comment: Hi thank you operator IN is super usefull but what i have to type instead of table_name ?

Comment: `table_name` (this is AR method) returns a real table name for model (It can be `stores` but I am not sure). So you can use code as it is or change `#{Store::Store.table_name}` to `your_real_table_name`

Comment: ah okay i tried this but
`>> Product.joins(:stores).where("product.stores.id IN (?)", params[:store_ids])
!! #<ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :store_product in model Product>`

Comment: This `product.stores.id IN (?)` confused me. Maybe `stores.id IN (?)`?

Comment: No, all variants says same error that has many association is not found.. i dont know how to setup :P

Comment: aw.. maybe my table is called stores_products im not sure if through parameter is table name or model class name i will check it. edit: no changes :p

Comment: i discover some mistake maybe.. please look
`>> @p = Product.new

=> #<Product id: nil, ...

>> @p.stores

!! #<ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :stores_products in model Product>`

Comment: I see. You have incorrect relations in your models! The [details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) are here. You should add `has_many :store_products` to Product and Store. Update: and through options should be pluralized `:through => :store_products` (it is necessary to test!)

Comment: ah right now it says `>> @products = Product.joins(:stores).where("stores.id IN (?)", params[:store_ids])
!! #<NameError: uninitialized constant Product::StoreProduct>`

Comment: try `has_many :store_products` and `has_many :products, :through => :store_products`

Comment: this throws that error too
`>> @products = Product.joins(:stores)`
`!! #<NameError: uninitialized constant Product::StoreProduct>`

Comment: smth is wrong in your app (relations, settings, structure). Rails goes to `Product::StoreProduct` instead of `Store::StoreProduct`. I think the reason is out of printed code and it is hard to guess what is wrong. I suggest to post more details (including folder structure for models) about your models. It can be useful to see at schema.rb as well.

Comment: please approve that in your code you have `has_many :store_products` and `has_many :products, :through => :store_products` in both models (Store, Product). You should make work this code: `store = Store::Store.new; store.products` and vice-versa `product = Product.new; product.stores`. After this all AR relations start to work properly

Comment: okay i edited my models (in question too) and `store = Store::Store.new` and `store.products` works, `product = Product.new` works too but `product.stores` throw `#<NameError: uninitialized constant Product::StoreProduct>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37866/discussion-between-gotva-and-muflix)